# uinavigationviewcontroller behaviour of not visible view controllers

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

If I have UINavigationController which currently displays MyViewController "a" and I push AnotherViewController "b" , later if i pop UINavigationController I'll get MyViewController "a" (exactly that MyViewController,not new). How can I get new instance of MyViewController displayed by NavigationController? Just push MyViewController "c"? is that ok that there still will be "a" in ViewControllers stack (memory problems etc)?

Answer (score 0):

For your b controller, use the view did appear method instead of viewdidload.  Also try to release anything with the view did disappear.  Sorry if this isn't an answer but your question is kind of misleading.